# How to find data and get text from html table td element next to it, without attribute using PHP Simple DOM?

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am using simple_html_dom.php for this task.

I wounder how can I get the value (plaintext) "Data c" or "Data F" from this kind of a table?

- TD elements doesn't have any attributes
- The "Data c" or "Data F" values can have different position - different indexes.

Is there a way frist to find td with value "Data A" and then using next_sibling() or previous_sibling() get and output the value "Data C"?

How to do this "find and get the data" next/before to the data that web have inside HTML table?

```
<table class="xyz">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Data A<p>data b</p>
</td>
<td>Data C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Data D<p>data e</p>
</td>
<td>Data F</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Or should I use some other tehnique?
Please could You help me with that?

Thank You!

Comment: Javascript is for client side stuff.

Comment: With PHP you simply dont

Comment: You can't do it easily with simple html dom. You can either loop through all the tds or find a lib that supports jquery-style selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quite easily retrieve the content from the various table cells with javascript - not sure if this is what you mean?

```
<script>
            var col=document.querySelectorAll('table.xyz td');
            for( var n in col ) if( n && col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ) console.log( 'Cell:%d Type:%s Value:%s',n,col[n].tagName, col[n].innerHTML );
</script>

will output
-----------
Cell:0 Type:TD Value:Data A<p>data b</p>
Cell:1 Type:TD Value:Data C
Cell:2 Type:TD Value:Data D<p>data e</p>
Cell:3 Type:TD Value:Data F
```